# GAS Dynamic Chart axis min and max, cant find the error

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, charts

Testing Spreadsheet for anyone that wants to test on it
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Q3z3hOuiixp7mWl0GUcN9Rc6HU1dS7ShJ996OyHugR0/edit?usp=sharing

EDIT: I installed an On Edit Trigger and now it works however the executions log now reflects 2 executions every time it triggers, one failed and one successful, any idea if this is normal? if not what should I do?

the failed execution says;
Exception: You do not have permission to call SpreadsheetApp.openById. Required permissions: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets
at onEdit(onEdits:4:28)

[image]

I have a spreadsheet with 4 charts (just line charts)
And each chart changes the data based on a dropdown, I also calculate the min and max i want from the data in a couple of cells next to it, the code basically is just trying to update the charts min and max when i edit the cell with the dropdown, but I cant find where is the error.

[image: The first chart of the sheet, the other 3 are similar]

```
function onEdit(e) {

  //run dynamic charts switch-case function
  const ss= SpreadsheetApp.openById("Sheet-ID");
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Analysis2.0");
  var range = e.range;
  var target = range.getA1Notation();
  const charts = sheet.getCharts();


  for (var i in charts) {
    let chart = charts[i];
    const chartName = chart.getOptions().get("title");

    if (target == "H18") {
      switch (chartName) {
        case "#0 Dynamic e1RM Chart":
          Utilities.sleep(200);
          var vaxis0min = sheet.getRange("E19").getValue();
          var vaxis0max = sheet.getRange("F19").getValue();
          chart = chart.modify()
            .setOption('vAxis', { minValue: vaxis0min })
            .setOption('vAxis', { maxValue: vaxis0max })
            .build();
          sheet.updateChart(chart);
          break;
      }
    }
    if (target == "X18") {
          switch (chartName) {
            case "#1 Dynamic e1RM Chart":
              Utilities.sleep(200);
              var vaxis1min = sheet.getRange("U19").getValue();
              var vaxis1max = sheet.getRange("V19").getValue();
              chart = chart.modify()
                .setOption('vAxis', { minValue: vaxis1min })
                .setOption('vAxis', { maxValue: vaxis1max })
                .build();
              sheet.updateChart(chart);
              break;
          }
        }
    if (target == "AN18") {
          switch (chartName) {
            case "#2 Dynamic e1RM Chart":
              Utilities.sleep(200);
              var vaxis2min = sheet.getRange("AK19").getValue();
              var vaxis2max = sheet.getRange("AL19").getValue();
              chart = chart.modify()
                .setOption('vAxis', { minValue: vaxis2min })
                .setOption('vAxis', { maxValue: vaxis2max })
                .build();
              sheet.updateChart(chart);
              break;
          }
        }
    if (target == "BD8") {
          switch (chartName) {
            case "#3 Dynamic e1RM Chart":
              var vaxis3min = sheet.getRange("BA19").getValue();
              var vaxis3max = sheet.getRange("BB19").getValue();
              chart = chart.modify()
                .setOption('colors', ['#990000'])
                .setOption('vAxis', { minValue: vaxis3min })
                .setOption('vAxis', { maxValue: vaxis3max })
                .build();
              sheet.updateChart(chart);
              break;
          }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, can you provide a copy of your spreadsheet in order to test this? Also, have you checked the execution logs? Can you see any error?

Comment: @Iamblichus Yeah I added a sample spreadsheet at the beginning of the post now, I checked the logs (silly me I didn't check them before) and turns out I don't have permissions to run the onEdit command, however I'm more familiar with web apps, for those they usually request authorization when I deploy them as web app, how can I make this script ask for the authorization sorry and thanks in advance because I probably should know this :(

Comment: Hi, I cannot see any link to the sample spreadsheet.

Comment: @Iamblichus my bad, now it is

Comment: I installed an On Edit Trigger and now it works!! but for some reason every time it triggers, the log reflects a failed and a successful execution, if this normal? if not any idea on how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Issue:

> I installed an On Edit Trigger and now it works however the executions log now reflects 2 executions every time it triggers, one failed and one successful, any idea if this is normal? if not what should I do?
>
> the failed execution says; Exception: You do not have permission to call SpreadsheetApp.openById. Required permissions: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets at onEdit(onEdits:4:28)

Simple triggers cannot access services that require authentication. Since [SpreadsheetApp.openById](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openbyidid) requires authentication, the function fails.

#### Solution:

If your script is bound to the spreadsheet, replace `SpreadsheetApp.openById` by [SpreadsheetApp.getActive()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#getactive), so that the script doesn't require authenticated access beyond the current document.

Otherwise, just remove the simple trigger (rename your function so that only the installed trigger runs - you might have to reinstall the trigger after changing the function name).

#### Reference:

- [Restrictions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#restrictions)

Comment: That would work however Im going to use another script to change the cell with the dropdown, ill probably use a web app to select what "exercise" I want displayed so I mostly wont use this with google sheets open, that's why I used open by ID


Maybe the way Im going to use it will always throw these 2 executions right?

Comment: @Rolroorlo Check the last paragraph in my answer. As long as your function is not named onEdit, there won't be a simple trigger. There's no need to keep both trigger and have both executions.